# Java Generics - Expected return type different than actual

Tags: java, generics

Here is an example of some code I'm working on:

```
public interface FooMaker<T extends Enum<T> & FooType>
{
      public List<Foo<T>> getFoos(String bar);
}
```

Let's further assume there will be many different concrete implementations of FooMaker.  So I wrote some code to utilize the FooMakers.

```
FooMaker<?> maker = Foos.getRandomMaker();
List<Foo<?>> fooList = maker.getFoos("bar");  //error here!
```

The second line of code causes the issue, eclipse tells me the code should be:

```
FooMaker<?> maker = Foos.getRandomMaker();
List<?> fooList = maker.getFoos("bar");
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the Foo declaration as the parameterized type in List has to go away to make the return type correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: What shall 'T extends Enum<T> & FooType' be? T has to be an enum and extend FooType, but you cannot extend an enum!

Comment: With generics, the keyword "extends" is used to describe implemented interfaces.  FooType is also an interface and you would still use the extends keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
List<? extends Foo<? extends Enum<?>>> fooList = maker.getFoos("bar");
```

The problem is that if this has been allowed:

```
List<Foo<?>> fooList = maker.getFoos("bar");
```

Then by extension, you would've been able to get away with this as well:

```
Foo<?> foo1 = new Foo<String>();
Foo<?> foo2 = new Foo<Integer>();
fooList.add(foo1);
fooList.add(foo2);
```

Which would invalidate the generic contract of the returned list.

To prevent this, the java compiler forces the return type to be wildcard-based, meaning Foo can be used as a return-type (to pull elements out of the list) but you will not be able to add wildcard-based Foo types to your list.

Comment: That makes perfect sense actually.  The invalidation is where everything gets whack.  Your suggestion works as advertised.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Usual:

```
class Bar {}
class Baz {}

FooMaker<?> maker = new FooMaker<Bar>();
List<Foo<?>> fooList = maker.getFoos("bar");  //error here!
fooList.add(new Foo<Baz>());                  //cock-up here!
```

Comment: I chose the other guy as answering the question because he included a way to work around my limitations, but I appreciate your input on why it doesn't work as I expected. +1

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring `maker` as `FooMaker<?>`. Why wouldn't you declare it as the type of `AwesomeFooMaker` if you know what specific `T` `AwesomeFooMaker` returns?

Comment: I'll edit my code a smidge.  I actually won't know which FooMaker I'll be getting.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. By declaring the type parameter as `?` you are stating "I have no idea what type this will return` and the compiler essentially acts as if any method related to the type parameter is now `?`, even if it's `List<?>`. Couldn't you use `FooMaker<? extends FooType> maker`?

Comment: The interface's return type is List<Foo<T>>, with my declaration I'm saying it could be any type T.  Even if I declare FooMaker<? extends FooType> maker, I still get a similar error.  I'm trying to understand why the Foo parameterized type is being ignored.